# filterTableViewController.reloadRows reloading rows only on first call

Tags: ios, swift3, tableview, uitableview

I have a table with 3 rows each with check button.What I am doing is when I select all the three buttons I want to click my cancel button which is on view not table on same controller to reload all 3 rows the call goes to custom cell class where uncheck is set to true and rows are reloaded.For the first attempt it works fine I can see correct index to be reloaded.On the second time again when I select all 3 check  buttons and click cancel again I can see correct index to be reloaded but the call is not going to custom cell class again the check box still remains checked.Any idea why?
**I am always getting correct index in my array.**

Cancel button code-:

```
@IBAction func cancelDataItemSelected(_ sender: UIButton) {
    for index in selectedButtonIndex{
            let indexPath = IndexPath(item: index, section: 0)
            print(selectedButtonIndex)
            filterTableViewController.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.none)
    }
    selectedButtonIndex .removeAll()
    print(selectedButtonIndex)
}
```

Table code-:

```
extension filterControllerViewController:UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate
{
    // NUMBER OF ROWS IN SECTION
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
      return ControllerData.count
     }

    // CELL FOR ROW IN INDEX PATH
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
     let Cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "filterCell", for: indexPath) as! ControllerCellTableViewCell
    Cell.filterTableMenu.text = ControllerData[indexPath.item]
     Cell.radioButtonTapAction = {
     (cell,checked) in
     if let radioButtonTappedIndex =  tableView.indexPath(for: cell)?.row{
        if checked == true {
          self.selectedButtonIndex.append(radioButtonTappedIndex)
    }
        else{
            while self.selectedButtonIndex.contains(radioButtonTappedIndex) {
                if let itemToRemoveIndex = self.selectedButtonIndex.index(of: radioButtonTappedIndex) {
                    self.selectedButtonIndex.remove(at: itemToRemoveIndex)
                 }
              }
           }
        }
    }
     return filterCell
}
```

Custom Class-:

```
var radioButtonTapAction : ((UITableViewCell,Bool)->Void)?
     //MARK-:awakeFromNib()
        override func awakeFromNib() {
            super.awakeFromNib()
            filterTableSelectionStyle()
            self.isChecked = false
        }

        // CHECKED RADIO BUTTON IMAGE
        let checkedImage = (UIImage(named: "CheckButton")?.withRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysOriginal))! as UIImage
        // UNCHECKED RADIO BUTTON IMAGE
        let uncheckedImage = (UIImage(named: "CheckButton__Deselect")?.withRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysOriginal))! as UIImage
        // Bool STORED property
        var isChecked: Bool = false {
            didSet{
                // IF TRUE SET TO CHECKED IMAGE ELSE UNCHECKED IMAGE
                if isChecked == true {
                  TableRadioButton.setImage(checkedImage, for: UIControlState.normal)
                } else {
                  TableRadioButton.setImage(uncheckedImage, for: UIControlState.normal)
                }
            }
        }
        // FILTER CONTROLLER RADIO BUTTON ACTION

        @IBAction func RadioButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
            isChecked = !isChecked
            radioButtonTapAction?(self,isChecked)
        }
```

Comment: Are the rows reloading? That is, are you getting calls to `cellForRowAt`? If so, what is that code?

Comment: @DonMag yes rows are reloaded when I use UITableViewRowAnimation.top I can see the rows reloading with animation but call never goes in custom cell class.Let me update the code

Comment: @DonMag updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fundamental misunderstanding of how "reusable" table cells work.

Let's say your table view is tall enough that only 8 cells are ever visible. It seems obvious that 8 cells will need to be created, and they will be reused when you scroll.

What may *not* be obvious is that the cells ***also*** are reused when they are reloaded. In other words, every time `.reloadData` is called - even if you are only reloading one cell that is currently visible - that cell is reused. It is *not* re-created.

So, the key takeaway point is: Any initialization tasks happen *only* when the cell is first created. After that, the cells are reused, and if you want "state" conditions - such as a checked or unchecked button - it is up to you to "reset" the cell to its original state.

As written, your `cellForRowAt` function only sets the `.filterTableMenu.text` ... it ignores the `.isChecked` state.

You can mostly fix things just by setting the cell's `.isChecked` value, but you're also tracking the on/off states in a much more complicated manner than need be. Instead of using an Array to append / remove row indexes, use an Array of Booleans, and just use array[row] to get / set the values.

Then your `cellForRowAt` function will look about like this:

```
// CELL FOR ROW IN INDEX PATH
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let filterCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "filterCell", for: indexPath) as! ControllerCellTableViewCell

    // set the label in filterCell
    filterCell.filterTableMenu.text = ControllerData[indexPath.item]

    // set current state of checkbox, using Bool value from out "Tracking Array"
    filterCell.isChecked = self.selectedButtonIndex[indexPath.row]

    // set a "Callback Closure" in filterCell
    filterCell.radioButtonTapAction = {
        (checked) in
        // set the slot in our "Tracking Array" to the new state of the checkbox button in filterCell
        self.selectedButtonIndex[indexPath.row] = checked
    }

    return filterCell

}
```

You can see a working example here: https://github.com/DonMag/CheckBoxCells

Comment: Awesome explanation man thanks a lot for clearing this out and showing some new idea of doing it +100 votes.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the cells are reused and that reloadRows just tells the rows to redraw. When a checkbox in a cell is checked by the user, the new checked state should be saved in the underlying data source, and the state marked in the cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath. Otherwise the cell checkbox shows the state for the last time it was set by the user for all indices and not the state for the underlying data source.

Comment: can you show me an example of what you talking about.Or tell me where I am wrong so that I can work on it.As a part of cell are reused I have 3 cell only.The part of cell visible at the first time before scroll are not reusable cell .Cells are only reused when they are scrolled out of visible screen.

Comment: look at your cellForRowAt delegate function. Are you drawing the checkboxes in there? I see you're setting the image for TableRadioButton in radioButtonTapAction. I don't see the new state being saved with the underlying data. So save the checked state in the underlying data, reload the data for the table (or just the row) and call TableRadioButton.setImage in cellForRowAt based on the data state.

Comment: When you change a cell directly, it will either be changed when you reload the data, or propagate to other indices as the cell is reused. Always draw the cells in cellForRowAt after reloading from the data source.

Comment: I save the check state on radio button click it goes true from false so as my isChecked is a stored property with  property observer didSet it execute the change in property and work for true condition.Then I pass around that true sate and cell with help of closure in my controller class and save the tapped index.Now when I again Tap on same button as the property is true it goes false and in my else condition I remove that save index from array.