# CheckBox on tableview duplicating, Swift, iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, select, checkbox

I have a tableView that when selected changes an image from one to another. This all works fine but when I select a tableCell it changes the image, but when I scroll it has also changed the image of another cell that I didn't select.

Below is my code.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FeaturesCell") as! FeaturesCell

    cell.featuresLabel.text = self.items[indexPath.row]

    return cell

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

     pickedFeatures.append(items[indexPath.row])

    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! FeaturesCell

    cell.checkImage.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "tick-inside-circle")

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    pickedFeatures.remove(at: pickedFeatures.index(of: items[indexPath.row])!)

    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! FeaturesCell

    cell.checkImage.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "No-tick-inside-circle")
}
```

If I use detqueureusable cell in the did select function then it just doesn't change the picture at all when selected.

Comment: this will answer your question-:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43686354/filtertableviewcontroller-reloadrows-reloading-rows-only-on-first-call. You actually need to save check box state .

Comment: Here is my demo https://www.dropbox.com/s/e43zk55surlwjlk/CollectionCkeck.zip?dl=0 its with collectionview but the logic may help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tableView.dequeueReusableCell(_)`, The problem is, you didn't maintain the status of the selected cells.

**Example :**

```
class viewController: UIVieWController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var selectedCellList  = [IndexPath]()

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FeaturesCell") as! FeaturesCell

        cell.featuresLabel.text = self.items[indexPath.row]

        if let _ = selectedCellList.index(of: indexPath) {
            // Cell selected, update check box image with tick mark
             cell.checkImage.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "tick-inside-circle")
        } else {
            // Cell note selected, update check box image without tick mark
            cell.checkImage.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "No-tick-inside-circle")
        }
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        pickedFeatures.append(items[indexPath.row])

        if let index = selectedCellList.index(of: indexPath) {
            selectedCellList.remove(at: index)
        } else {
            selectedCellList.append(indexPath)
        }
        tableView .reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you @Subramanian. This worked perfect, but your explanation was also a help. Sometimes a little explanation can go along way to making others better programmers. So thank you for that. All the best.

Comment: @Subramanian Your solution worked perfectly for me as well but is it possible to persist the checkboxes data?

Comment: @Saurabh Then, you need to update your model based on the selection.

Comment: @Saurabh `selectedCellList` already holds the index selected cell. If you have index then you should be able to get the model from your data source and update the model

Comment: @Subramanian Ok. I will give a try, whatever happens i will let you know.